# Is there a way to identify current layout details with renderings?

Tags: presentation

I got a scenario where I have different layouts Layout1, Layout2, so on...I have a renderings which is shared among this layouts. 
Layout1- Rendering -R1
Layout2-Rendering-R1
and so.

Now I have situation where I want to identify the layout name or details within this rendering R1. I know this is not good idea still is there any way to refer the details of layout within renderings.

Comment: By "different layouts", do you mean that you have a number of template fields that have presentation settings in them? Or do you mean you have the same rendering in multiple placeholders?

Comment: Actually a Layout in presentation not fields. In mvc way, i got layout and partial view. Is there a way i can check the layout details as in say name or something within partial view.

Comment: Are you just wanting to know the layout for the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you want to handle a particular rendering R1 based on the underlying Sitecore layout selected for the page item

The below screenshot shows how to get the layout information from the current rendering:

[image]

Here's a code sample that gets the current layout name:

```
Guid layoutId = Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingContext.CurrentOrNull.Rendering.LayoutId;
Item item = Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(layoutId));
string layoutName = item["Name"];
```

Comment: Could you add a code sample for accessing current layout details (such as its name)?

Comment: From Sitecore perspective LayoutId is just a GUID and we can use it to retrieve the LayoutItem using Sitecore Data API and pull its fields. John West [blog](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/accessing-items-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms) gives multiple ways of accessing it.

Comment: In my opinion, without a code sample, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko here you go :) `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item = 
  context.GetItem(layoutId); var fieldValue = item["FieldName"];`

Answer (score 7):

You can access the layout in your code by using `Sitecore.Context.Item.Visualization.Layout` (example for context item). This will give you a `LayoutItem` that gives you access to the name, physical file, ...

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko - The above code gives the Layout item without the need to use Data API.